# Create a hashmap that contains strings and a list in powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, hashmap

In powershell how does one create a hashmap that contains a string as the key and a list of strings as the values?

For example, in Java, the following can be done:

```
Map<String, List<String> myMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>();
```

Does powershell contain this capability?

I've tried:

```
$myMap = @{ [string], New-Object Collections.Generic.List[string] }
```

But this didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
$myList = New-Object Collections.Generic.List[string]
$myList.Add("one")
$myList.Add("two")
$myList.Add("three")

$myHash = @{ }
$myHash.Add("list", $myList)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$myMap = @{ "Michigan"="Detroit"; "California" = "Sacremento","Hollywood";"Texas"="Austin" }
```

Note how California has two values assigned to it's key. Also note how you will run into trouble if you ever try to export this to csv, the enumerator skips over the array value and just inserts "System.Object[]" into the csv file, probably as it should.

To dynamically update the list,

```
$myMap.California += "Compton"
```

Comment: I need to be able to add strings dynamically to a list

Comment: @inquisitor you should update your question then, but I have updated my answer.